# Freeze the game

Tags: c#, xna

Is there any function to freeze all the game or a certain class for a moment?

I'm searching for a Wait function like in Matlab.

Thanks.

EDIT: The wait function stops all the processing for a given time.

Comment: I don't think there is a builtin way to do that, because its to dependant on the subsystem. Maybe you want the logic and physics to freeze but the music should keep playing. You will have to implement it in your update logic of the specific components your self.

Comment: A simple Google doesn't reveal documentation for a "Wait" function in Matlab. Can you provide a link so we know exactly what you're after? Or, better yet, describe it yourself? Your question is a bit ambiguous otherwise (there are many different ways in which you can "freeze" the game).

Comment: As dowhilefor said, i'll implement in the update to block some animation or input (after a hit for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-line hack would be to call Thread.Sleep(x) in the main Update(), but that'll *hang* the game for the specified amount of time. The user will think your app has become unresponsive and he might kill it and restart it! It's probably not what you want.

The way I architecture games, each major component has its own Update() (or Tick()) method that is called on each logical update. You can selectively freeze components by simply not calling their Update() for a while. There are things you certainly never want to freeze, like refreshing the screen, responding to user input or sound processing.

Some example code:

```
// To pause the game for x number of frames, set pauseDelay = to x
int pauseDelay;

public void Update() {
     if (pauseDelay > 0) {
         --pauseDelay;
     }
     else {
         physics.Update();
         ai.Update();
     }
     input.Update();
     sound.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've based your game on GameComponents you can usually just set the Enabled flag to false which prevents the update logic being executed, this obviously depends on other factors (Object manipulation outside of the classes update logic, update logic being performed in the draw or other method ect..)

```
public class Car : GameComponent
{
    // This logic is only called if the Enabled property is set to true.
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

If you've not used game component then it would be quite simple to introduce an Enabled flag to your clases and check for that before executing update logic.

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for a very simple way (Andy's seems better, but this is quick way)

In your update Method a class, add at the top:

```
if (isPaused)
break;
```

You can use isActive to check is the window is active too.